# How to slice and grouping array every two values?

Tags: php, arrays, logic

I have saw the group of array like this:
[image: Imgur]

And the array like this:

```php
[1] => Array (
    [bid] => 2
    [board_name] => Test1
    [create_date] => 2019-04-25 12:28:14
    )
[2] => Array (
    [bid] => 3
    [board_name] => Test2
    [create_date] => 2019-04-25 12:28:14
    )
[3] => Array (
    [bid] => 4
    [board_name] => Test3
    [create_date] => 2019-04-25 12:28:14
    )
```

How can it build `<tr>` for every two arrays?
Like this:

```html
<tr>
  <td>Test1</td>
  <td>Test2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Test3</td>
</tr>
```

Is it count every two arrays and then group them into new array??

I'm still learning about php, maybe this question is hard to be understood what I means, sorry for my bad English..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need [array-chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

This is simple example:

```
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$chuncks = array_chunk($input_array, 2); // contains [[a,b], [c,d], [e]]
```

Now you can use it to build the `<tr>` part as :

```
foreach($chuncks as $c) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo implode("</td><td>" , $c);
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Does not really help the OP build the HTML Table though

Comment: Probably, but that was the main part of the question _How can it build <tr> for every two arrays?_

Comment: @dWinder Yes I can generate html table by myself, I just want to know the logic about **grouping every 2 arrays**

Comment: @carry0987 As I said - you can use the `array_chunk` for that as: `array_chunk(array_column($array, "board_name"))`

Comment: @dWinder I'm trying not to use implode, since this function is hard for me to insert into my code, but the logic is right, thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2):

Try using [array_chunk](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to format your array

```
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
        )

)
```

Comment: Does not really help the OP build the HTML Table though

Comment: Holy #$%^#$(%^#$ I cannot believe I've lived this long without this function :'(